# What regex syntax does Sublime Text use?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext4

What regex syntax does Sublime Text use?
POSIX? POSIX Extended?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sublime Text's [`Find` and `Replace` functions](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/search-and-replace.html), along with [snippets](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html), [are powered by](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/regex-support-doesnt-st2-use-the-boost-library/5126/2) Boost's [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions) [engine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex). For syntax highlighting, Sublime Text 3 and 4 use a custom [oniguruma](/questions/tagged/oniguruma)-compatible engine, with fallback to [Oniguruma itself](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kkos/oniguruma/v6.9.1/doc/RE), for [`.sublime-syntax`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html) files. Oniguruma is used for the older `tmLanguage` format, and was the only engine used for syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2.

Comment: That engine doesn't seem to support all PCRE patterns, e.g. `\p{Zs}`.

Comment: @msoutopico I believe there have been significant changes to the regex engine in Sublime Text 4, although I can't remember off the top of my head whether it was just for syntax highlighting, or both that and Find/Replace. The best place to ask would be [Discord](https://discord.gg/HcmwdVK), as some of the devs hang out there, along with others who are extremely knowledgeable about Sublime's internals.

Comment: @msoutopico also, do you know in what version `Zs` was added to PCRE? It may be that Sublime uses an earlier version, or that it's in a module that wasn't included...