# Match all characters in a line between matching symbols or end of the row

Tags: regex

I want to match on all the words between the `|` and the end of the row (VEHICLE and all the Vechicle names). I don't want the extra lines matched

I've started with this regex but this wouldn't exclude the symbol `|`:

```
^\|.*$
```

So then I tried this syntax, but it leaves off the last word on the line:

```
(?<=\|)(.*)(?=\|)
```

Samples:

Text above I don't want matched

```
| VEHICLE | Truck | | Bike
| VEHICLE | Car          | | Scooter
| VEHICLE | Sedan | Mini Van    | 
| VEHICLE | Sedan | white, brown, black |     
| VEHICLE | Sedan | pack/cars   |
```

Text below that I don't want matched

Comment: I see that you have given some examples. Can you tell me which bits you want matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match only the words, you could first match a pipe and a whitespace character. Then capture in a group one or more word characters followed by using  a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check what is on the right side is either a whitespace character or the end of the string.

Your values are in the first capturing group.

`\|\s(\w+)(?=\s\||$)`

**Explanation**

- `\|\s` Match `|` and a whitespace character
- `(\w+)` Capture in a group 1+ whitespace characters
- `(?=\s\||$)` Positive lookahead to assert what follows is either a whitespace character of the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQcsOi/1)

**Update:**

To only match the words in Sublime including matching 1+ tabs you could use:

`\|\h+\K\w+(?:[,\/]?\h*\w+)*(?=\h*(?:\||$))`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pbnhwb/1)

**Explanation**

- `\|\h+` Match a pipe followed by 1+ horizontal whitespace characters
- `\K` Forget what was currently matched
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[,\/]?\h*\w+` Match an optional comma or a forward slash followed by 0+ times a horizontal whitespace character and 1+ word characters
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?=` Positive lookahead to assert what follows is

  - `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace characters
  - `(?:\||$)` Match either a pipe or the end of the string
- `)` Close positive lookahead

Comment: The answer almost works but has 2 issues:
1. It doesn't capture words that are followed by tabs
2. It includes the `|`, which I want to exclude since I'm using this in Sublime syntax file

Comment: Apologies, realized another complication in my sample data that I should have called out. Sometimes the words to be captured are more than 1 word and/or are a comma separated list: 
a) Mini Van
b) car, van, truck
c) pack/cars

How do I modify the \w+ line to capture these use cases

Comment: @TommyWu Do you mean like this? `\|\h+\K\w+(?:[,\/]?\h*\w+)*(?=\h*(?:\||$))` [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pbnhwb/1)

Comment: that's exactly right, thank you! Now I just have to figure out why it's not working in my Sublime syntax highlighter.

Comment: @TommyWu When you use find and enable the regex, do you see your matches?

Comment: while I see matches when I test out my data with regex101.com I  do not see any matches in Sublime. Oddly, Sublime will save the changes I made to the syntax file, which usually is an indication it accepts the syntax.

Comment: @TommyWu That means that the regex works but you don't see the matches? I see the matches when I run this on ubuntu with Sublime version 3.1.1 and version 2.0.2

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you said. Yes, Sublime Search with regex will find the correct matches. The syntax file (YAML format) does not seem to find any matches

Comment: @TommyWu I see you asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567446/sublime-custom-syntax-highlighter-not-matching-the-same-as-search-with-regex) and when I read [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343933/type-of-regex-used-by-sublime-text-3), I think the `\h` is not supported. You could use a character class which will match a space or a tab like `[ \t]` For example `\|[ \t]+\K\w+[^|[ \t]]+(?:[,\/]?[ \t]*\w+)*(?=[ \t]*(?:\||$))` [Regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/aN3QRRkWFj)

Answer (score 1):

Repeat any character *but* a `|` in the middle, and in the lookahead, alternate between the `|` and the end of the line:

```
(?<=\|)([^\|]+)(?=\||$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/YmtEPE/1

Note that there probably isn't any need for the capturing group in the middle, it's equivalent to the entire match anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
[^|\s](?:[^|]*[^|\s])?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2Cuit/1)

**Details**

- `[^|\s]` - any char but `|` and whitespace
- `(?:[^|]*[^|\s])?` - an optional sequence of any 0+ chars other than `|` followed with any char but `|` and whitespace.

Comment: Your solution works great for this section of text but I have regular text in other rows in the same file. How would I modify the text you provided above to include ONLY lines that start with `|`?>

Comment: @TommyWu You probably might want `(?:\G(?!\A)\h*\|\h*|^\|\h*)\K(?:[^|\s](?:[^|]*[^|\s])?)?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2Cuit/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can go with:

```
(?<=\| *)[^|\s]+(?= *\||$)
```

**Details**:

- `[^|\s]+` - matches all characters except white-spaces and `|` 1+ times.
- `$` - matches end of a string (or a line when `m` flag is enabled).

[Demo here](https://regexr.com/442pe)

Update:

> `(?<=\| *)(?! +)[^|]+(?= *\||$)`

Comment: Your syntax seemed to work great but I noticed 2 issues:
1) It doesn't allow tab whitespace after any of the words
2) Looks like Sublime's Syntax highlighter (YAML) won't accept it.

Any ideas?