# Regex: extract characters from two patterns

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have the following string:

```
https://www.google.com/today/sunday/abcde2.hopeho.3345GETD?weatherType=RAOM&...
https://www.google.com/today/monday/jbkwe3.ho4eho.8495GETD?weatherType=WHTDSG&...
```

I'd like to extract `jbkwe3.ho4eho.8495GETD` or `abcde2.hopeho.3345GETD`. Anything between the `{weekday}/` and the `?weatherType=`.

I've tried `(?<=sunday\/)$.*?(?=\?weatherType=)` but it only works for the first line and I want to make it applicable to all strings regardless the value of `{weekday}`.

I tried `(?<=\/.*\/)$.*?(?=\?weatherType=)` but it didn't work. Could anyone familiar with Regex can lend some help? Thank you!

[**Update**]
I'm new to regex but I was experimenting it on sublime text editor via the "find" functionality which I think should be PCRE (according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35343933/type-of-regex-used-by-sublime-text-3))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?:sun|mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur)day\/\K[^?]+(?=\?weatherType)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3nnaCQ/1)**

[**Link to Code**](https://regex101.com/r/3nnaCQ/1/codegen?language=php)

---

**Explanation:**

- `(?:sun|mon|tues|wednes|thurs|fri|satur)day` - matches the day of a week i.e, `sunday`,`monday`,`tuesday`,`wednesday`,`thursday`,`friday`,`saturday`
- `\/` - matches `/`
- `\K` - unmatches whatever has been matched so far and pretends that the match starts from the [current position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573989/5331061). This can be used for the PCRE.
- `[^?]+` - matches 1 or more occurences of any character that is not a `?`
- `(?=\?weatherType)` - the above subpattern`[^?]+` will match all characters that are not `?` until it reaches a position which is immediately followed by a `?` followed by `weatherType`

To make the match case-insensitive, you can prepend the regex with `(?i)` as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/Nur6PV/1)

Answer (score 1):

In the examples given, you actually only need to grab the characters between the last forward slash ("/") and the first question mark ("?").

You didn't mention what *flavor* regex (ie, PCRE, grep, Oracle, etc) you're using, and the actual syntax will vary depending on this, but in general, something like the following (Perl) replacement regex would handle the examples given:

```
s/.*\/([^?]*)\?.*/$1/gm
```

There are other (and more efficient) ways, but this will do the job.

Comment: Thanks, initially I didn't know there're so many types of regex. I just updated my post.